# Pivot monthly data from the past years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the data from my original query:

| Store Name | Month | Transaction Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 - Loc1 | 2018December | 245 |
| 0002 - Loc2 | 2018December | 261 |
| 0001 - Loc1 | 2018November | 232 |
| 0002 - Loc2 | 2018November | 218 |
| 0001 - Loc1 | 2018October | 123 |
| 0002 - Loc2 | 2018October | 144 |
| 0001 - Loc1 | 2019January | 312 |
| 0002 - Loc2 | 2019January | 287 |

I'm trying to convert Transaction Count and Month (w/ year) columns into rows. I'm hoping for this result:

| Store Name | 2018October | 2018November | 2018December | 2019January |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 - Loc1 | 123 | 232 | 245 | 312 |
| 0002 - Loc2 | 144 | 218 | 261 | 287 |

The query I'm currently trying resulted to this message : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.

Here's the latest query with pivot:

```
(SELECT b.[Name] 
        ,CONCAT(YEAR(a.[Date]),'',DATENAME(MONTH,a.[Date])) AS 'Month'
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT a.[Receipt Num]) AS 'Count'
        ,a.[Store Num]
FROM [dbo].[TransSales] a

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Location] b
      ON b.[Code]=a.[Store Num]

WHERE a.[Store Num] in ('0001','0002') AND
      a.[Date] BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2021-06-30' 

GROUP BY b.[Name]
         ,CONCAT(YEAR(a.[Date]),'',DATENAME(MONTH,a.[Date]))
         ,a.[Store Num]
 )


SELECT * 
FROM SALES
PIVOT
(COUNT (DISTINCT [Receipt Num])
    FOR [Month] IN ([2018December]
,[2018November]
,[2018October]
,[2019January]
)) P


;
```

Comment: Usually this is achieved in whatever tool you are using to present the data, after being provided with the output of your original query.  Do you really need to be doing this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, I think you should be handling this `pivot` in your presentation layer, be it Excel, SSRS, Power BI or whatever.  Going forwards, this will be a much more maintainable solution as you will not need to either keep updating your `Month` column listing or rely on dynamic SQL.

Also, I would advise that you stop using reserved keywords such as `Date`, `Month` and `Count` as a column name and that you properly alias your tables rather than using `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.  These things make the code harder to read, write and maintain for literally zero benefit.

That said, if you plan on persisting down this route, your issue in the code is related to not referencing your source columns correctly.  Assuming that your initial query is within a `CTE`, you should be referring to the `Count` column name rather than `count(distinct [Receipt Num])` that populates it.

Consequently, your script should look something like this:

```
with sales as
(
    select l.[Name] as LocationName
            ,concat(year(s.[Date]),'',datename(month,s.[Date])) as TransactionMonth
            ,count(distinct s.[Receipt Num]) as Transactions
            ,s.[Store Num]
    from [dbo].[TransSales] as s
        left join [dbo].[Location] as l
              on s.[Store Num] = l.[Code]
    where s.[Store Num] in ('0001','0002')
      and s.[Date] between '20181001' and '20210630' 
    group by l.[Name]
            ,concat(year(s.[Date]),'',datename(month,s.[Date]))
            ,s.[Store Num]
)
select * 
from sales
pivot(sum(Transactions)
      for TransactionMonth in ([2018December]
                              ,[2018November]
                              ,[2018October]
                              ,[2019January]
                              )
      ) as p
;
```